# Accept either type

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Basic 2010, I would like a function that accepts 2 possible types.

So for example, something like this:

```
 Public Function test(ByVal value As Int32 Or Int64) As String
```

I know that I can just use this:

```
 Public Function test(ByVal value) As String
```

And it will accept either type. But I am just wondering if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, method overloading is possible in VB.NET. Just give both methods the same name but different argument lists:

```
Public Function test(ByVal value As Int32) As String
    Return test(CLng(value))
End If

Public Function test(ByVal value As Int64) As String
    ' Do something useful
End If
```

All the first function does is to convert the argument to an Int64 (`Long` in VB.NET) and call the second function. You can replace `CLng` with `Convert.ToInt64`, if you prefer the CLI terminology.